# C++: Text file not being read

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print string values from a text file to the console but the file isn't opening.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include<fstream>

int main()
{
    ifstream nameFile;
    nameFile.open("E:\\Names.txt");
    string a;
    int studentCount = 0;

    if (nameFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(nameFile, a)) {
            cout << a << '\n';
            studentCount++;
        }

        cout << studentCount;
    }
    else
        cerr << "Unable to load file" << endl;}
```

Comment: And the file `E:\Names.txt` actually exists?

Comment: Yes it is on a flash drive currently connected to the computer

Comment: Please add what c++ compiler you are using, operating system, and your current user permissions.

Comment: This code does not even compile with a standard compiler. Please **Cut and Paste** your exact code.

Comment: How did you determine that the file isn't opening? Was "Unable to load file" printed?

Comment: Whoops, you're right... I read something wrong. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Check if the ifstream really has the contents of the file. If it doesn't exist you won't read anything at all